# Show a particular method of API on Azure developer portal and not all the methods

Tags: azure-api-management

I have 4 methods in my API and I only want to show 3 methods/operations on developer portal. Is there a way I can restrict that?

I am using new developer portal.

Also I also want to show only those APIs to user for which user has subscribed to. I could not find any document for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to hide the endpoints in an API.
You can create two swaggers separating the endpoints and create the API. Subscribe users to the API which the user needs.

OR

You need to tweak the preview templates with conditions etc,but this is not recommended.

Comment: creating 2 swaggers means creating 2 APIs right? How can they have same base path then? Problem is we have created OPTIONS API for CORS and dont want to show OPTIONS API to developers.

Comment: Yes, I meant 2 APIS. But it doesnt provide the same app prefix. If you only want to hide all the OPTIONS endpoint, you can edit the templates for operations. Add a condition if the method is not OPTIONS, show the operation. check more on template edit here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-developer-portal-templates. This is not highly recommended.